# Why is rails console ignoring my config/database.yml development: settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

My database.yml file specifies a non-default database: and no explicit username:. If I use `rails c` and try to access anything it fails with, e.g.:

```
2.2.2 :001 > User.connection
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "scope" does not exist
```

If I try to explicitly connect using my :development settings I see:

```
2.2.2 :005 >   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :development
 =>
#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:...
 @config={:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :database=>"scope", :pool=>5, :timeout=>5000, :port=>5432, :username=>"scope", :password=>"...", :host=>"127.0.0.1"},
...
```

So it's clearly ignoring my custom database and my own username. Oddly enough, if I rename the yaml block from `development:` to anything else, e.g. `staging:`, I can connect fine with a `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :staging` and access my models.

Anyone know what could be going on? I do not have a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable set, so that can't be overriding things. What else could be causing this behavior?

Here's the actual yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mydb_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  port: <%= ENV["BOXEN_POSTGRESQL_PORT"] || 5432 %>
```

And a stacktrace:

```
2.2.2 :002 >   User.count
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "scope" does not exist

    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:665:in `rescue in connect'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `connect'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
... 11 levels...
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Documents/projects/deliveries/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.2 :003 >
```

**UPDATE**
Using a new shell and connecting to the console seemed to magically fix things. I still don't know what originally corrupted things though...

Comment: mind sharing your `database.yml`?

Comment: Please share the `database.yml` and the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: @nayiaw and kmrakibulislam updated

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: XXX_development
    host: localhost
    pool: 5
    username: yourusername
    password: yourpassword
```

Comment: My bad, I actually did have database: formatted as X_development. But explicitly adding the username/password fields as well did not change the problem of it assuming a default db name of scope and user of scope. Thanks though.